# How to apply condition for pure rolling when we have a shifted centre of mass for a rotating body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics

> A small particle of mass $m$ is attached at $B$ to a hoop of mass $m$ and radius $r$. The whole system is placed on the rough horizontal ground. The system is released from rest when $B$ is directly above $A$  and rolls without slipping . Find the angular acceleration of the system at the instant when $AB$ becomes horizontal as shown in the figure.

[image]

I'm trying to solve this question by the torque method. The torque equation about the centre of mass which is at a distance of $\frac{R}{2}$ from A. It will include the torque due to Normal from ground and the static friction and torque due to the weight of both cancels out.

Now, **the main confusion is writing the force equations in the horizontal direction and what will be the condition for pure rolling as now the center of mass is not exactly at center of system**. Here is my try:

> Firstly, I assumed the horizontal acceleration of center of mass as $a$, then for writing the no slipping condition, I wrote the acceleration of bottom most point P as $a_P=r\alpha$ where $r$ is $\frac{\sqrt5 R}{2}$ and took it's component along the horizontal and equated to a by which we get $a=R\alpha$ (It seems I'm going wrong here). Then $$N\frac{R}{2}-f_sR=I\alpha$$ where $I=\frac{3MR^2}{2}$, then using $f_s=2ma$ and solving, we get $\alpha=\frac{2g}{7R}$, not the correct one.(where $N=2mg$)

The underlying concept where I am feeling that I am lagging is maybe the acceleration of centre of mass will be in both $x$ and $y$ direction, and also point $P$ will have centripetal acceleration too.

Comment: Your question asks "What am I doing wrong?" which is typical of homework-like and check-my-work questions. Phrasing your question as such makes it easy to be closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126893/discussion-between-community-and-archisman-panigrahi).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647868/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647882/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647917/2451

Comment: @Community Hi! I have edited your question and voted to reopen. I have edited keeping in mind to get right to the 'point' of what you are asking, right now the placement of the grey box looks a bit weird. Please check it out and edit the question accordingly

Comment: By the way, one of the users had created a [meta thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13656/can-we-reopen-this-mechanics-question) about this question. Might be worth checking out

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511190/ (actually exact same lol)